# Binary compression algorithm with decompress by index

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, information-theory, data-compression

I have a list of 256-bit binary data to store. Any algorithm for doing lossless compression on it in a way I can retrieve an entry by its index without decompressing the whole data (if possible). The decompressed data will also be stored as binary. I will also need to code this algorithm ground-up in a domain-specific language.

I'm trying to store 256-bit addresses in a blockchain smart-contract. I will need to later lookup addresses by index so, it'd be helpful if I can do that without full decompression.

Sample data with each entry pasted end to end [here](https://0bin.net/paste/UiqHxmfC#Is2kblvQZn5m5aL4D3bvTso0H2zirR4mDDuvOVWnF1n). I tried [this site](https://planetcalc.com/9069/)
to compress using LSW and it seems I get a good reduction. Also [here](https://0bin.net/paste/O8+17lFx#lH8yQkawGVukWYW2xyThEkLeqW6cBPrtnMihEF9Ax1N) is another sample with each entry separated with line-break. The real data will contain from 2 to 65,000 entries.

Comment: I doubt that this will be answerable with the information provided.  I think you need to provide more context, e.g., about the nature of the data.  A trivial compression algorithm is "do nothing" and that will meet all of your stated requirements, so do you have some additional requirements, such as ensuring a certain level of compression or something?

Comment: A hash code could do, but collisions are possible. What can you say about the sparseness of the data ?

Comment: A binary trie can do the job, but will cost one pointer per entry.

Comment: How significant was the reduction? And did it compress well because each entry itself compresses well or because the entries are somehow related? Can you share the entries? Seems hard to solve without being able to analyze them.

Comment: "seperated by a linebreak" btw sounds suspicious, as the entries themselves could already contain linebreaks. Unless you wrote them in hex or so, in which case that might explain the significant reduction.

Comment: Please don't use "edit:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: Telling me the data is binary does not really help.  I already knew it was binary.  I don't know what "slightly random" means.

Comment: I'd expect a significant data sample to be helpful, along with information on the amount and how "random access decompression" is an issue.

Comment: Looks like I was right, and you don't actually get any compression other than due to the conversion to the bigger alphabet. Your original data has about 100,000 bits and the LZW site's result is about 120,000 bits.

Comment: @KellyBundy I pasted the continous data on planetcalc and it says Number of bits in the original text: 204800 and Number of bits in the compressed message: 119794. Some error in the site? The data must have 102400 bits right?

Comment: @NoelJacob Actually it should say (and does for me) that the input is 819200 bits. Because it's 102400 characters, which with most(?) encodings are encoded as one *byte* each. How did you get 204800, what settings did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compress blockchain addresses (in any blockchain I am familiar with), so this is a dead end.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I've revised my answer.  I've tried to get the questioner to provide context but they have have unfortunately not been terribly successful.  This is one of the problems with unclear/vague questions -- it is easy for answers to end up being not useful to the asker, and it can be hard to judge which answers will meet the criteria.

Comment: Right, they could've provided better information, didn't really address my own questions/suggestions, either. If the question gave details for "seems I get a good reduction", we could at least show that/why that's mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

Due to nature of data, just storing the data is better of than compressing it.